# Creating new types using Typedef on Vibe.data.json.Json, implicit conversion error

Tags: d, dmd, vibed

I needed to have multiple types of Json so I used `Typedef` as following:

```
 alias NewType = Typedef!(Json);
```

I am using Vibe.d Json version, I get the following message when compiling using `DMD64 D Compiler v2.072.0`:

```
Error: cannot implicitly convert expression ([cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u, cast(ubyte)0u]) of type ubyte[] to void[32]
```

I read the documentation and did not find any limitations for using `Typedef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error in `Typedef` it seems it is not able to alias a type which use array of type `void`, Same problem exist with `JSONValue` from std_data_json. In this case I change this line: https://github.com/s-ludwig/taggedalgebraic/blob/master/source/taggedalgebraic.d#L58 to `ubyte` type and it is working now. I will try look at it further and fix it.

[Issue link](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17036)